# vs2010 designer duplicate control from base class

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, designer

Folks,

I have form(formA) that derived from another form(formB)(that derived from DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraUserControl).

In base form i have control - public DevExpress.XtraBars.BarManager barManager;

When i open inherited form in vs2010 designer this control(barManager) gets duplicated in derived form.

I use vs2010 ultimate SP1. My colleagues do the same - but control didn't duplicated they use VS2010 SP1 too. May be it's settings of vs2010 ? How to fix it ?

Thanks,

Dzmitry

Answer (score 0):

As I remember, there in DevExp settings is a setting that enable/disable edit of DevExp control`s child controls. Maybe it is the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Installation of DevExpress fixed this problem(first time i've just added some assemblies to GAC).